# Objective function of Bayesian Model Averaging

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, inference, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian

I am quite confused about the objective function of the bayesian model averaging in the paper "[Bayesian Averaging of Classifiers and the overfitting Problem](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/mlc00b.pdf)".[1](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/mlc00b.pdf)

On the section 2, here is the first equation:

> Let $n$ be the training set size, $\mathbf{x}$ examples in the training set, $\mathbf{c}$
>   the corresponding class labels and $h$ a model (or hypothesis) in the
>   model space $H$. Then, by Bayes’ theorem, and assuming the examples are
>   drawn independently, the posterior probability of $h$ given $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c})$ is given by:
>
> $Pr(h|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c})=\frac{Pr(h)}{Pr(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c})}\prod_{i=1}^{n}Pr(\mathbf{x_i},\mathbf{c_i}|h)$  (1)
>
> where $Pr(h)$ is the prior probability of $h$, and the product of $Pr(\mathbf{x_i},\mathbf{c_i}|h)$ terms is the likelihood.

I could understand that the Eq(1) uses conditional independence.

> In order to compute the likelihood it is necessary to compute the
>   probability of a class label $\mathbf{c_i}$ given an unlabeled example $\mathbf{x_i}$ and a hypothesis $h$, since $Pr(\mathbf{x_i}, \mathbf{c_i}|h) = Pr(\mathbf{x_i}|h)Pr(\mathbf{c_i}|\mathbf{x_i}, h)$. This
>   probability, $Pr(\mathbf{c_i}|\mathbf{x_i}, h)$, can be called the noise model, and is
>   distinct from the classification model $h$, which simply produces a
>   class prediction with no probabilities attached.

I can understand the above as well.

Then

> Finally, an unseen example $x$ is assigned to the class that maximizes:
>   $Pr(c|x,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{c}, H)=\sum_{h\in H}Pr(c|x,h)Pr(h|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{c})$ (4)

I have two questions:

1. I don't understand how to deduce the Eq(4);
2. In those euqations of Bayesian Model Averaging, which are variables?
   I don't understand how to train it.

Thank you in advance.

[1](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/mlc00b.pdf) Domingos, P., (2000)
"Bayesian Averaging of Classifiers and the Overfitting Problem"
Proceedings of the Seventeenth International Conference on Machine Learning, pp.223-230

Answer (score 0):

After days' consideration, I think I might know how to deduce:

$Pr(c|x,\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}, H)
=\frac{\sum_{h\in H} Pr(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}) Pr(x) Pr(h|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}) Pr(c|x, h)}{\sum_{h\in H} Pr(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}) Pr(x) Pr(h|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c})}
=\frac{\sum_{h\in H}Pr(h|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}) Pr(c|x, h)}{\sum_{h\in H} Pr(h|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c})}
=\sum_{h\in H}Pr(h|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c}) Pr(c|x, h)$

I can't be certain though.